# Transacting API for Datomic

Tags: clojure, datomic

Certainly a dumb question, but hopefully should clear things up.

I am following along https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/getting-started/transact-schema.html, and the step to transact the schema, in this tutorial, is

```
user=> (d/transact conn {:tx-data movie-schema})
```

However, when I try this, I get

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to java.util.List  datomic.api/transact
```

Instead, when I just do

```
(d/transact conn schema)
```

it works for me. Is the tutorial missing some subtlety here? Am I missing something? (the only difference is that I'm using the Free version instead of the Starter Pro version).

**Edit:** the initial version of this post mentioned the schema, but this is generally true for just adding new facts too (i.e. using `{:tx-data foo}` doesn't work, but just using `foo` does).

Comment: I've noticed another inconsistency: while my toy example now works (yay), the result is a hash-set, while the result in the tutorial is a vector; not sure what to make of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the cause of your problem here is an inconsistency between the [Peer API](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/clojure/index.html#datomic.api/transact) (in which `transact` accepts a list) and the [Client API](https://docs.datomic.com/client-api/datomic.client.api.html#var-transact) (in which `transact` accepts a map containing a `:tx-data` key). I suspect you tried to run your REPL commands in the REPL of a Peer process, whereas the [tutorial](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/getting-started/transact-data.html) you linked to [expects](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/getting-started/connect-to-a-database.html#add-dependency) you to run commands in the REPL of a Client process.

Why the inconsistency between Peers and Clients? Not being part of the Datomic team, I can only speculate:

1. The Peer API was designed before the Client API historically, at which time the 'transaction requests as lists' format was sufficient
2. When the Client API was designed, because of the more expensive nature of calling `d/transact` (I believe it incurs an additional I/O roundtrip from client to server), the authors left room for additional data in transaction requests (e.g for templating), hence the more extensible map-based format.

Comment: That makes sense! I'm not sure why I ended up in the REPL of the "wrong" process, but this would explain the inconsistency I observed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the possible cause of the difference! The error message is rather hard to understand for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can see a working demo here:    https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic

Just clone the repo and run the tests:

```
~/tupelo-datomic > lein test

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic._bootstrap

----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.9.0    Java 10.0.1
----------------------------------

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.bond

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.bond-query

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.core

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.find

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.functionality

lein test tst.tupelo-datomic.quick-start
:using-local

Ran 17 tests containing 110 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
~/tupelo-datomic >
```

---

Regarding your specific question, I have only used `:tx-data` as a field from the ***output*** of Datomic operations.  I have never used it as a field from *input* data.  It is possible that the docs you reference are incorrect or out of date.

Here is an example (note the parens instead of curly braces):

https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic/blob/master/src/tupelo_datomic/core.clj#L540

---

For more detail, you can see the native Datomic function call as the output of the wrapper function `new-attribute` in the unit tests:  https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic/blob/master/test/tst/tupelo_datomic/core.clj#L46

```
  (let [result (td/new-attribute
                 :weapon/type :db.type/keyword
                 :db.unique/value :db.unique/identity :db.cardinality/one :db.cardinality/many
                 :db/index :db/fulltext :db/isComponent :db/noHistory)]
    (is (s/validate datomic.db.DbId (:db/id result)))
    (is (wild-match? {:db/id          :* 
                      :db/ident       :weapon/type
                      :db/index       true 
                      :db/unique      :db.unique/identity
                      :db/noHistory   true
                      :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many
                      :db/isComponent true
                      :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db
                      :db/fulltext    true 
                      :db/valueType   :db.type/keyword}
          result)))
```

Comment: Thanks, my (surprising?) conclusion is that everything works (and works well!) but the docs were out of date.